# Is there an Implementation of the Hilbert curve from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^n$, where $n$ is large? ($n=10,000$, say)

Tags: visualization, high-dimensional

I would like to map each point in $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^n$ with a Hilbert curve, where $n=10,000$. That is
$$
f: [0,1] \to [0,1]^n,
$$
is the $n$-dimensional Hilbert curve.

I found the library of [Cortesi](https://github.com/cortesi/scurve),
or the code given in [Sergeyev, Strongin and Lera](http://books.google.ca/books?id=ZXM8AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA119&dq=sergeyev+strongin+lera&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gRhPUvmqLKGGyAGGxIHQDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=sergeyev%20strongin%20lera&f=false) book.

Cortesi library used a system of index, so I don't have a map $f$.
The code from the book gives a map $f$, but it has trouble with large $n$.

If possible, I would like a pointer to a freely avaible code.
Or some papers/advices on how to write such an $f$.

My use case is that I have a function
$$
G: [0,1]^n  \to \mathbb R,
$$
that I would like to visualize in 2D with
$$
H = G \circ f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R. 
$$
So I want $f$ to be a Hilbert curve, so that set containments are preserved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have time to get all the details down, but maybe this answer can give some helpful intuition.

Basically, something that will work is taking the first $N$ binary binary of your number in $[0,1]$ and assigning them as the most significant digits for each of the $N$ dimensions (so, the first decimal digit is the most significant digit in the first dimension, the second decimal digit is the most significant digit in the second dimension, and so on). Then, you perform a change of coordinates in the $[0,1]^N$ interval you are mapping to involving translations/rotations/reflections *that depends on which ones were the previously read $N$ digits*, and repeat the procedure.

A procedure in the case of $N=2$ that looks to me like it is following this model is given here: http://bit-player.org/2013/mapping-the-hilbert-curve. The operators for the change of coordinates are what they call the $H_i$. The main computational difference with your situation is that instead of considering quadits (groups of two bits, or which is the same, digits from $0$ to $3$), you are considering groups of $N$ bits (or which is the same, digits from $0$ to $2^N - 1$. Your $H_i$ operators will operate on size $N$ vectors, not size $2$ ones. And there will be $2^N$ of the $H_i$ operators, so you will not be able to precompute all of them.

Hope this clarifies more than it confuses.

Also, how much of this is a problem depends on the function you are trying to plot, but an issue you are likely to face is that to get a single digit of precision in each of the N coordinates, you must have $N$ digits of precision in your real number between $0$ and $1$. And 10,000 digits of precision is quite a bit : )